# Multiple-page printing from datagrid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, air, flex4

From [this](http://blogs.adobe.com/koestler/2010/05/printing_in_air_2.html) tutorial i've got a good result printing , and [this](http://dryicons.com/blog/2008/04/26/multiple-page-printing-from-a-html-adobe-air-application/) tutorial on how to print multiple pages from html, i'm trying to do the same with a `Datagrid`.
my problem is when the number of rows exceed the height of `Datagrid` so i tried to break it down to several pages, this is my code:

```
            protected function button3_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var success:Boolean = printJob.start2(disablePageRange.selected ? this.printUIOptions : null, false); 
            var pjo:PrintJobOptions = new PrintJobOptions;

            if (methodBitmap.selected){
                pjo.printMethod = PrintMethod.BITMAP;
            }
            else if (methodVector.selected){
                pjo.printMethod = PrintMethod.VECTOR;
            }
            else{
                pjo.printMethod = PrintMethod.AUTO;
            }

            if (printJob.maxPixelsPerInch > 600){
                pjo.pixelsPerInch = 600;
            }

            updateForm();
            updateThePage();
            updateTheWindow();  

            //--------------------------------------
            var b:int = 0;
            var H:int = myDataGrid.rowHeight *2;
            for each (var item:Object in meme as ArrayCollection ){

                if (H > myDataGrid.height){

                    myDataGrid.dataProvider = arlst; 
                    printJob.addPage(thePrintableArea, null, pjo);
                    arlst.removeAll();

                    H = myDataGrid.rowHeight *2;


                    b++;
                    //Alert.show(b.toString());
                }else{
                    arlst.addItem(item);
                    H += myDataGrid.rowHeight;
                }
            }
            printJob.send();
        }
```

The result: i get the first page but the rest are just blank `Datagrid`:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This answers: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7c7e.html

Summary:
create external `Itemrenderer` and populate the data to it.